# avoiding the import "regenerator-runtime/runtime"

Tags: javascript, jestjs, babeljs, parceljs

I am using Parcel to bundle my project and jest to run my tests.

Everything works fine, but on tests that I have the `async/await` keyword, I had to import `regenerator-runtime/runtime`

Like this:

```js
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime"

test("read armored key", async() => {

})
```

And this work.

But without this import (`import "regenerator-runtime/runtime"`) I got this error message:

```
ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
```

How can I change my project to run without this import on tests with async?

Example: https://github.com/skhaz/parcel-regeneratorRuntime-is-not-defined

Comment: if you're targeting newer browsers you could set the browserslist params to target newer browsers. like this in a package.json file: "browserslist": [
    "Chrome 70",
    "Edge 17",
    "Firefox 68",
    "Opera 60",
    "Safari 12"
  ] ..... google to see how to use browserslist without package.json if your project is set up in another way.

Comment: It's for NodeJS, not for browsers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Depending its version, not all features available in your browser runtime will work in the Node runtime. Promises (with `await/async`) *are* supported in current versions of node, but since **you are using Parcel, which by default uses Babel**, your `async/await` calls will be compiled to use `regenerator-runtime`, a polyfill for that functionality. You can either `import "regenerator-runtime/runtime"` in [every entry file](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#usebuiltins-entry) (not recommended if you don't need the polyfill!), or you can tell babel what your runtime is.

You should be able to get it to work with the [@babel/preset-env](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env) preset, configured like so in your `.babelrc`:

```json
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "10" // the target node version, boolean true, or "current".
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

See this [Medium article](https://medium.com/@binyamin/enabling-async-await-and-generator-functions-in-babel-node-and-express-71e941b183e2) for more information about configuring babel for this:

> I found [this answer to my troubles](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/484) and it worked when I implemented it.

---

<sup>**Opinion**:  
  
Don't rely on zero-configuration tools like Parcel: they end up adding to your development time by creating unexpected behavior (like your issue), or you have to spend time learning how it works. It's enough to debug your own application; you shouldn't have to debug your build tool as well.</sup>

Answer (score 8):

As I know that you can configure `@babel/preset-env` to compile against current node version which is described [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#targetsnode) then it should work:

`.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When using Webpack, or [Parcel](https://flaviocopes.com/parcel-regeneratorruntime-not-defined/), add the below to `package.json`:

```
"browserslist": [
  "since 2017-06"
]
```

or

```
"browserslist": [
  "last 3 Chrome versions"
]
```